# Calling postmessage with user defined message on checkbox's click event

Tags: mfc

I have MFC dialog based application in windows OS.

I need to execute 10 commands(API) when checking the checkbox. I need to log each API's result in the richeditctrl immediately each api is executed.It will take 1 minute to execute these 10 commands

For that I am calling postmessage on checkbox click event. I am facing below problems.

- The checkbox is displayed with checked state only after the completion of
  ON_BN_CLICKED event.
- The richeditctrl is getting updated with text only after the completion 
  of ON_BN_CLICKED event. It is not getting updated when each api is
  executed.

  ```
  void CUtilityDlg::OnBnClickedCheck1()
  {
      if(m_ctrlAutomate.GetCheck())
      {
          PostMessage(WM_USER_MY_OWN_MESSAGE);
      }
  }


  LRESULT CUtilityDlg::OnUserDefinedMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
      Automate();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: You probably need to use threads here. However without more information it's hard to tell. Especially we need to know what `Automate()` does. Also tell us what `WM_USER_MY_OWN_MESSAGE` is. Is it in the `WM_USER+X` range or in the `WM_APP+X` range?

Comment: Indeed, you need to create at least one additional thread. 1 minute is quite a long time, and you could simply display a hourglass cursor while the request is being processed, but this is rather not acceptable, according to your "specs". The main (UI) thread should best own all windows and handle all UI interaction. The background (worker) thread(s) should perform the commands you mentioned, and when a command finishes post user-defined message(s) to a window of the main thread, in response to which you should update your status (rich-edit) control.